# What is an Ornament Word™?

Tags: wordplay, pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an ***Ornament Word™***.  Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]

Text version:

```
Ornament Words™    Non-Ornament Words™     Special Ornament Words™
potted             abuzz                    gallop
billon             beaux                    halloo
postage            gauzy    
gammon             heavy    
pottage            hallux   
stubborn           abnormal 
succor             foster   
subdeacon          offstage 
nonsuch            posting  
portside           gadfly   
onstage            cheeky
```

**Bonus Question:**

> What are Special Ornament Words?

Hint 1:

> To answer this riddle, you'll need to see the words from a different perspective.

Hint 2:

> If this were a word, it would be an Ornament Word: `ablmvw`

Hint 3:

> Bill Gates can’t melt steel beams

Comment: just to be clear, "billon" is meant as in the alloy of precious metal, not "billion" as in 1000 million?

Comment: Correct. And, fun fact: the word "billion" is a Non-Ornament Word.

Comment: The only letters not in an Ornament word are **FJKQVWXYZ**, which are all worth 4 or more points in Scrabble.  The only other letter worth 4 or more points is **H** (which is in an Ornament word (*nonsuch*)).  This could just be a reflection of the fact that some property of ornament words favours more-common letters.

Comment: Brilliant observation that is indirectly connected with the underlying property, but not for the reason you've outlined.

Comment: I also feel like the prevalence of double-letters is somewhat significant. Or perhaps Parseltongue is just being tricky and messing with us, it could be a red herring

Comment: No intentional deception here, Cubemaster!

Comment: Maybe if you want people to solve it you should give hints :P

Comment: One interesting property of the 2 "Special Ornament" words is that if you take the numerical letter values (A=1 and so on), they both add up to 63. Even more interesting is that "gallop" becomes "halloo" by adding 1 to the first letter (g -> h) and subtracting 1 from the last letter (p -> o).

Comment: @tjs352 very good observation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have it!

An Ornament Word is one that when:

> Converted to the WingDings font, contains consecutive 'groups' of characters with no singletons

This fits the clues/hints because:

> 'Wingding' was derived from 'Windows Dingbats' where a Dingbat is a type of printing *Ornamentation.*    Additionally, clue 3 clearly hints at the weird conspiracy involving Wingdings, Bill gates, and 9/11.

The nature of this question makes it hard to type out examples/proof... here's a couple:

> [image: Answer]

EDIT: And, a 'Special Ornament Word'

> Works in uppercase Wingdings too

Comment: Lord almighty that was hard

Comment: Wow!  Congrats. Did the third hint give it away?  I am so impressed you got this after the third clue

Comment: I wasn't even close until Clue 3, but got the reference immediately.  That said, I wasn't positive until I made the connection to the word 'Ornament,'  which was enough to convince me I was definitely on the right track.  Still, it took me a while to see the pattern even AFTER making the conversion.  Very tricky puzzle!

Comment: Particularly impressed that you figured out to capitalize the Special words!  Fun fact: those might be the only two english words that are "special ornament words"